# change default icons main.dart

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

[image]

the icon main.dart does not show by default
This is a normal situation?
help me please

did the default settings android studio, nothing came out

Comment: what do you mean by default icon

Comment: are you using vscode?

Comment: if your program is running then there's no problem

Comment: i am using android studio

Comment: everyone shows the same icon, but i am not show the same

Answer (score 0):

If you have doubt in installation of android studio then you can run command(flutter doctor) in cmd. If the android studio is not installed then you will get (X) sign in android studio. And if every thing is ok then you can check the vs code extension section you have to install dart in vs code